# Is it possible to insert hyperlinks in an ReST literal block?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, docutils

I know this kind of defeat the purpose of a literal block, however I was wondering if there was any workaround to achieve this. My use case is to put an hyperlink in a block literal of pseudo code, in order to reference details elsewhere in the document.

Example :

```
Look at this JSON pseudo code
-----------------------------

::

  {
    "id": <number>,
    "name": <string>,
    "big_property": <see schema of big_object_>
  }

And the details of big object
-----------------------------

.. _big_object:

::

  {
     <another_schema>
  }
```

I would like that in the first literal block, `big_object_` becomes an hyperlink.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`parsed-literal`](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#parsed-literal-block) directive for this:

```
.. parsed-literal::

  {
    "id": <number>,
    "name": <string>,
    "big_property": <see schema of big_object_>
  }
```

Comment: That's perfect thank you ! Somehow it was impossible to find that by googling "restructuredtext hyperlink in literal blocks" or variants, I was convinced there was no solution :D